# Using GMock to verify a Destructor Call

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

Using GMock, how can I verify that a class's destructor is called? Is there a way, other than to [wrap it in another class](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/source/browse/trunk/test/gmock-more-actions_test.cc?r=327#530)?

The obvious method, `EXPECT_CALL(object, ~classtype())` yields a compiler error (gmock cannot produce a mock method called `gmock_~classtype`).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An easy way to check for a destructor call:

```
class MockFoo : public Foo {
  ...
  // Add the following two lines to the mock class.
  MOCK_METHOD0(Die, void());
  virtual ~MockFoo() { Die(); }
};
```

In your test function:

```
 MockFoo* foo = new MockFoo;
  ...
  {
    EXPECT_CALL(*foo, Die());
  }
```

More Details can be found here:
[Mocking Destructors](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-destructors)

Comment: The link gives 404 now.

Comment: Link to cookbook is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're passing `--gmock_catch_leaked_mocks=0`, then gmock should already be detecting when you fail to destroy a mock.  The destructor is where unsatisfied expectations are flagged as errors, so gmock has special support for detecting when it is not called.

Comment: There's a caveat, though: GMock will *not* detect leaked mocks that doesn't have any expectations attached to them (ON_CALL / EXPECT_CALL). This is because leak check is based on information that is stored in special entity called GTest registry, and mocks without expectations are not registered in it.